# Unable to open Chrome UI with Jenkins installed as Windows Service even on Windows Server 2019 even after doing necessary configurations

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, jenkins-plugins

Unable to open Chrome UI with Jenkins installed as Windows Service even on Windows Server 2019 even after doing necessary configurations

I have installed Jenkins as service on Windows Server 2019 . I did the following

1. Open properties window of the service -> Logon-> enable the checkbox "Allow service to interact with desktop"
2. Toggled the NoInteractiveServices registry key from 1 to 0 .

3)Restarted Server as well as Jenkins

Still i am not able to see the Chrome Launch from Jenkins (Its working fine as headless)

I know that we by launching from .war file we can see the browser open . But when i navigate to folder and launch the war file jenkins gets opened but all my configured jobs are not visible

Please provide workaround for any of above

Comment: Are you using the `correct` `home` `directory` when launching from `.war` file ?

Comment: i am opening cmd from where jar file is located i.e in Program files /Jenkins  and then opening it

Comment: Using `Admin` permission ?

Comment: @Akzy What do you mean by Admin permission ?

Comment: Execute the script by admin right - *run as administrator*